# Migrate data from Informix to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, migration, informix

I have tried with sqoop but its slow. Any fast approaches to move data from informix to cassandra?

Sqoop is stuck here for long.

```
INFO  12:53:17  Consistency level for reads from cfs: LOCAL_QUORUM
INFO  12:53:17  Consistency level for writes into cfs: LOCAL_QUORUM
WARN  12:53:18  Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform...
using builtin-java classes where applicable
INFO  12:53:18  Successfully loaded CFS compression rules for filesystem: cfs
INFO  12:53:20  Using read commited transaction isolation
INFO  12:53:20  Running job: job_201607121017_0008
INFO  12:53:21   map 0% reduce 0%
```

Comment: Could you please share the sqoop command you are using?

Comment: Can you add any information about the size of the Informix table(s) you are exporting?  Are there any unusual data types in them?

Comment: May be for a billion records in informix table

Comment: bin/dse sqoop import --connect jdbc:informix-sqli://$HOST/$HO_SCHEMA:INFORMIXSERVER=$DB_SERVER --driver com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver --username $USER --password $PASSWORD --table TABLENAME --target-dir $PARENT_PATH/filename --where "table_column < $COSTRAINT" $PARAM -m 1